# how to create auto increment field in odoo 9

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

In my model, I want to create auto increment field, I 've tried to follow some tuts unfortunately all tutorials just working in odoo 8 to under.
I just follow instruction from some threat in odoo 9 in this link 
[auto increment - internal reference odoo9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266106/auto-increment-internal-reference-odoo9)
It was working by answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/3734244/danidee
but still not working for me. Here is my model:

```
class cashadvance(osv.osv):
    _name = 'comben.cashadvance'
    _columns = {
        'sequence_id': fields.char(string='Sequence ID', help="Auto Generate"),
    }

 @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        vals['sequence_id'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('seq.cashadvance')
        return super(cashadvance, self).create(vals)
```

and this is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="cashadvance_seq" model="ir.sequence">
          <field name="name">No_PD</field>
          <field name="padding">3</field>
          <field name="code">seq.cashadvance</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

the code above showing no error but the sequence_id field keep empty when I click save button.
Help me Please...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with following code.

Replace *create* method with

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    vals['sequence_id'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('comben.cashadvance')
    return super(cashadvance, self).create(vals)
```

Replace *xml* file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="cashadvance_seq" model="ir.sequence">
          <field name="name">No_PD</field>
          <field name="padding">3</field>
          <field name="code">comben.cashadvance</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Afterwards restart odoo server and upgrade your module.

NOTE:

When you upgrade module and it has *.xml* file with  will not upgrade. So first remove *noupdate="1"* attribute and upgrade module. Check flow. It should work fine. Don't forget to place again *noupdate="1"* on sequence view file.

Make sure you have given .xml file in __ *openerp*__.py file

Comment: I tried your code but still not working, Something weird about this, I checked in table ir_sequence in postgresql, the sequence "comben.cashadvance" does not exists. I've removed noupdate="1"  and put it again exactly the same as your instruction, but failed, more help please @Odedra

Comment: it solved by reinstalled the module, thank you so much @Odedra, you've saved my days... ;)